# Turn off a portion of the screen's LEDs

Tags: android, user-interface, window, pixel, led

I'm working on a side project that requires a portion of the screen's LEDs to be turned off to get a pure dark experience. By this I do not mean setting sections of the window's pixels to black (#000000) since in this case, the pixels are technically still lit. If you view black pixels in a dark room, you will see a glow indicating that the LEDs are on.

For example, most OLED Android devices support the ability to check the time and notification icons by either tapping on your screen, lifting your device, or waving your hand over the camera. In this example, the Android system only turns on the LEDs that are required to show the time and notification icons while all the other LEDs remain off to conserve battery consumption. Because this behavior is a feature specific to OLED screens, I do not plan to support non-OLED screens.

I am trying to accomplish this same behavior within an Android application. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to accomplish it?

Comment: I am not aware that this is available to ordinary apps.

Comment: Did i understand right, that you are trying to achieve OLED feature in LED screens?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev No, I am trying to achieve a feature specific to OLED devices. My requirements will not work on non-OLED screens. Any reference to the term "LED" in my question refers to a diode in an OLED screen.

Comment: Did you find any solution to it ?